# Confusion about {{run_id}} and {{parent_run_id}} variables for Databricks jobs (Azure)

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

In Databricks jobs on Azure you can use the `{{run_id}}` and `{{parent_run_id}}` variables for a specific run: https://docs.databricks.com/workflows/jobs/jobs.html

For Databricks jobs with only two or more tasks, then `{{run_id}}` seems to correspond to `task_run_id` and `{{parent_run_id}}` seems to correspond to the `job_run_id`.

For Databricks jobs with only one task, then `{{parent_run_id}}` seems to correspond to the `task_run_id`, but what does the `{run_id}}` correspond to? Is that the `job_run_id`?

Comment: I am under the impression that nowadays - all jobs are considered as MULTI_TASK jobs only. So when you say it is a single job, it is a job with a single task - Also can pls let me know where I can find this parent_run_id ? I tried using the databricks cli `databricks runs get --run-id 123` - which seems to be giving only run id. A job has a run id say 123, and the task has another run - id say 456. In case of multiple tasks, each has a different one. But I am able to find no reference to parent_run_id.

Comment: Did you take a look at https://docs.databricks.com/workflows/jobs/jobs.html  {{parent_run_id}} is mentioned there

Comment: I did see it, I am just wondering a practical scenario for its usage, or as it states in the link - it maybe only to set context to a job - as in what job triggers the child task. Just a guess though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received the following answer from Databricks:

> Yes, you are correct in your understanding that in Databricks jobs
> with multiple tasks, the `{{run_id}}` variable corresponds to the
> `task_run_id` and the `{{parent_run_id}}` variable corresponds to the
> `job_run_id`.

For Databricks jobs with only one task, the `{{parent_run_id}}` variable still corresponds to the `task_run_id`, which is the unique identifier for that particular run of the task. In this case, the `{{run_id}}` variable would correspond to the `job_run_id`, which is the unique identifier for the entire job run that includes that single task.

So, in summary:

- For Databricks jobs with multiple tasks: `{{run_id}} = task_run_id`, `{{parent_run_id}} = job_run_id`
- For Databricks jobs with only one task: `{{run_id}} = job_run_id`, `{{parent_run_id}} = task_run_id`

Link: https://community.databricks.com/s/question/0D58Y00009vaoZiSAI

Answer (score 1):

The {{run_id}} variable is a unique identifier for a run of a Databricks job. This identifier is generated by Databricks and is used to track the progress of a job run.

[image]

The {{parent_run_id}} variable is a unique identifier for the parent run of a Databricks job. This identifier is generated by Databricks and is used to track the relationship between a parent run and its child runs.

[image]

Task 1 and Task 2. When this job runs, a new run ID is generated for the job run, and two run IDs are generated for the task runs of Task 1 and Task 2. In this case, the {{parent_run_id}} variable will refer to the run ID of the job run, while the {{run_id}} variable will refer to the run ID of the current task run. So, in Task 1, {{run_id}} will refer to the run ID of Task 1, and {{parent_run_id}} will refer to the run ID of the job run. Similarly, in Task 2, {{run_id}} will refer to the run ID of Task B, and {{parent_run_id}} will refer to the run ID of the job run.

In summary, the {{run_id}} variable always refers to the run ID of the current task or notebook, while the {{parent_run_id}} variable always refers to the run ID of the parent process that triggered the current run.

You can use these variables to monitor the progress of your Databricks jobs and to track the relationships between parent and child runs.